# Excel count number of values based on another column

Tags: excel

I want to count the number of times a value appears based on the criteria in another column. Eg, for the example below I want to search the data and lookup how many times ART has a 2 and a 3, etc. I want to display these results on a separate worksheet

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: In general, it is preferable to include the data as actual text, as you originally had, rather than using an image.

Comment: thanks. Ill take note. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

Use `COUNTIFS`:

```
=COUNTIFS(C2:C10,"ART",M2:M10,"=2")
```

The above formula would count the number of times where the class is art and the overall value is 2.

Comment: thank you! Its simple when you know how! I was very much over thinking it! Thanks again :)

Comment: please mark correct thanks